# Vertical lines between points with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to `ggplot2` and cannot figure out how to draw vertical dotted grey lines between

the points/dots along the x-axis. Here's my example code:

```
d1 <- runif(10,10,15)

d2 <- runif(10,25,30)

d3 <- rep(1:10,2)

df <- data.frame(x = d3, y = c(d1,d2))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +

geom_point()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your actual data is structured like the one used for your example, just add `geom_line(aes(group = d3))` to the plot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +  
 geom_point() + geom_line(aes(group = d3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that solution! Easy and works great. Also thanks for the other solutions and to clarify I want the line only between the 2 points and not an extension past the points!

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely better ways than this but:

```
d1 <- runif(10,10,15)
d2 <- runif(10,25,30)
d3 <- rep(1:10,2)
df <- data.frame(x = d3, y = c(d1,d2))
df$place <- rep(c("min", "max") , each=10)

df_wide <- reshape(df, direction = "wide", v.names="y", timevar="place", idvar="x") 

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=y.min, yend=y.max), 
        size=1, data=df_wide, colour="grey70", linetype="dotted") +
    geom_point()
```

Though I'm not sure what you mean by "along the x axis", maybe you want it to extend top to bottom not just between the points.

Comment: And if you're new to ggplot I'd recoment these three websites: a) http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/ ;
b) http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/docs/ ;
c) http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `geom_vline()` to do this.

```
        d1 <- runif(10,10,15)
        d2 <- runif(10,25,30)
        d3 <- rep(1:10,2)
        df <- data.frame(x = d3, y = c(d1,d2))
       ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
geom_vline(xintercept = df$x, linetype= 3, colour = "#919191")
```

Comment: are the lines supposed to extend past the points?  (I was unsure of this myself)

Comment: I'm guessing so that's why I came up with this solution. Not clear from the question.