# Plot overlapping vertical lines with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, network-programming, reshape

I have a list of time-ordered pairwise interactions. I want to plot a temporal network of these interactions, which would look something like the diagram below.

[image: Temporal Network Example Image]

My data looks like the example below. The id1 and id2 values are the unique identifiers of individuals. The time indicates when an interaction betweens those individuals occurred. So at time = 1, I want to plot a connection between individual-1 and individual-2.

```
id1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 2, 1)
id2 <- c(2, 4, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5)
time <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df <- data.frame(id1, id2, time)
```

According to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253239/vertical-lines-between-points-with-ggplot2), I can see that it is possible to draw vertical lines between positions on the y-axis in ggplot. This is achieved by reshaping the data into a long format. This is fine when there is only one pair per time value, but not when there is more than one interacting pair at a time. For example in my dummy data, at time = 2, there are three pairs (in the plot I would show these by overlaying lines with reduced opacity).

My question is, how can I organise these data in a way that ggplot will be able to plot potentially multiple interacting pairs at specified time points?

I have been trying to reorganise the data by assigning an extra identifier to each of the multiple pairs that occur at the same time. I imagined the data table to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIUKZ.png), but I haven't figure out how to make this in R... In this example the three interactions at time = 2 are identified by an extra grouping of either 1, 2 or 3. Even if I could arrange this I'm still not sure how I would get ggplot to read it.

Ultimately I'm trying to create someting that looks like Fig. 2 in this [scientific paper](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1005527#).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this without reshaping the data, just set one `id` to `y` and the other `id` to `yend` in `geom_curve`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = id1)) +
    geom_curve(aes(xend = time, yend = id2), curvature = 0.3) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1:7, colour = scales::muted("blue")) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    geom_point(aes(y = id2), size = 3) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, max(df$time) + 1)) +
    theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow cool, so much simpler than I imagined. I guess yend was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

Libraries:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('data.table')
```

Data:

```
id1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 2, 1)
id2 <- c(2, 4, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5)
time <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df <- data.frame(id1, id2, time)
setDT(df)
df1 <- melt.data.table( df, id.vars = c('time'))
```

Plot:

```
p <- ggplot( df1, aes(time, value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_curve( mapping = aes(x = time, y = id1, xend = time, yend = id2, colour = "curve"), 
              data = df, 
              curvature = 0.2 )
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is great!

I guess I was quite close but the reshaping was actually simpler than I realised. 

:)