# dplyr::group_by is affecting a column of vectors unexpectedly, resulting in "Each group consists of only one observation..." error

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

This is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850189/revisit-geom-path-each-group-consists-of-only-one-observation-do-you-need-to), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation#comment42674683_27082601), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation).

I have a `data.table` that looks something like this:

**animal_frame**

```
first_and_last    animal    color
c(1, 2)           dog       red
c(2, 2)           cat       red
c(4, 2)           dog       green
c(3, 1)           dog       red
c(4, 6)           pig       green
c(3, 3)           cat       red
c(4, 2)           pig       red
```

`animal_frame$num_entry = sample(1:nrow(animal_frame), nrow(animal_frame), replace=FALSE)` gives me an indexing column.

Here, the x-axis is `num_entry` and the y-axis is `first_and_last`, resulting in two points for every tick on the x-axis. Each of these points is to be connected with a vertical line as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253239/vertical-lines-between-points-with-ggplot2) question:

```
ggplot(data=animal_frame, aes(x=num_entry, y=first_and_last)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=num_entry, color=color)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green"="green", "red"="red"))
```

This works well. Now, I'd like to facet this same plot according to `animal`, but I want an indexing column (beginning from 1) *for each* animal. So, using `dplyr`, I run:

```
animal_frame %<>%
  group_by(animal) %>%
  mutate(facet_num_entry = sample(1:n(), n(), replace=FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Now, I try:

```
ggplot(data=animal_frame, aes(x=facet_num_entry, y=first_and_last)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=facet_num_entry, color=color)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green"="green", "red"="red")) +
  facet_grid(animal ~ .)
```

But receive **geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?**

When I look at the data frames, it looks like when I add the `num_entry` column, there are two entries for every sampled number (I suspect this comes from the fact that each entry in `first_and_last` is a vector. This appropriately gives me two observations to group by—and thus two points to draw a vertical line between.) On the other hand, when I add the `facet_num_entry` column, there's only *one* entry for every sampled number. I think there may be something going on with the collapsing of `first_and_last`? But I've been screwing with this for a while and can't figure it out.

Also, if there's an easier way to structure my data such that these vertical lines are possible, feel free to suggest it. I couldn't find anything as easy as making `first_and_last` a column of vectors.

Comment: what's the downside of separating `first_` and `_last` ?

Comment: @StephenHenderson I thought that might be easier, but I wasn't able to get a vertical line segment through those two points in the same way—so, I suppose, the downside would be that I wouldn't know how to connect them w/ a vertical line segment using `geom_line` (or whatever else might be used).

Comment: Does your index need to be random, the way it would be from `sample`? Or do you want to just number the rows, which you could do for each group independently?

Comment: @camille It doesn't *have* to be random, but if I don't randomize it, R orders them according to the first element of `first_and_last`, giving the impression of a relationship that isn't actually there (going from smallest to largest). (On a related note, though, I've solved my problem using `geom_segment`! I'll write up an answer when I finish)

Comment: Okay. Try `df %>% group_by(animal) %>% mutate(index = row_number())`. That gives a numbered index within each group